# Angular 5 chrome browser view issue

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, browser, ngx-translate

I am using angular 5 for my project, recently I am facing an issue with window's Chrome browser, the value exists/ Showing in chrome developer tools but not reflecting in UI however this issue is not every time.

added video screenshot. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1czm7vNdPoDFOqe3rt0QLnWIOEuXsdgP9/view

[image]

Comment: Does it get highlighted in Augury in the same place?

Comment: An image says less than a few lines of code. Include the component code (simplified) or a Stackblitz example app instead. You're sure it's not an issue with the CSS/markup? I doub't it's a Chrome bug.

Comment: I am sure issue is not related to CSS, when I perform any event on the element  / sometimes some other element suddenly label will appear.the issue is not only limited to static label some times for form elements also

Comment: It is a CSS transition issue, when I decrease div transition speed from 0.5 to 0.4 it works fine. Thanks.